# Esc button on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

Hi i was doing a report and went on google drive and accidently clicked on full screen and it said I needed to click <kbd>esc</kbd> to get out of full screen.

I was just wondering where the <kbd>esc</kbd> button on an iPad is, because I can't find it and I need to insert a picture and I can't and it won't let me copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

There is no escape key on iPad.

Furthermore, I tried connecting my Apple Wireless keyboard to my iPad via bluetooth. I went  on Google Docs (desktop version) and went fullscreen. The escape key on the keyboard is not recognized. Same with the Smart Keyboard on the iPad Pro line - no physical escape key was made.

We can assume iOS has not support for that kind of key yet and with this long, it’s not in the cards for this platform.

That being said, all sorts of apps have custom on screen keyboards that let you touch to send escape key (like [prompt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt-2/id917437289?mt=8) ssh app by Panic). For many apps, the tab key serves the same function as esc but certainly not all.

The actual fix is to engage the vendor of the app (or designer of the web page that assumes an escape key is present) to get them to fix their app/design.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. All you have to do is hold down the screen until the pop up shows then press “exit full screen” then you will be back to editing. Hope this helps. <3

Answer (score 1):

Got into the same trouble 7 years later,,,

I got into the full screen mode on Google Draw.

The way out is subtle but easy

Just tap on any area twice and a context menu will pop up giving you a n option to exit the full screen mode[image]

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> worked for me in Excel.

Comment: How does this apply on an iPad? Are you using an external keyboard?

Answer (score -2):

Well, there is no ESC key. but the homebutton on the middle bottom of the ipad functions about the same as the ESC key...